# Separating duplicate values VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that contains 3 columns: name, city and education.

In column A (Names) I have duplicate values.
I want to separate it from other duplicate values in column A something like this shown in image below below.

Is it possible using VBA?

[image]

Comment: Yes it is possible, but how good is your VBA knowledge?

Comment: Do you want to delete / remove duplicates? Or do you want to insert a blank row between two different names in column A? How does your initial data look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will add a blank row where `Names` is different. Assume `Names` in column A:

```
Sub SeparateDuplicates()
    Dim lastCell As Integer

    lastCell = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lastCell To 2 Step -1
        If Range("A" & i) <> Range("A" & i).Offset(-1, 0) Then
            Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Alex but it is inserting blank rows in column A i want to insert blank rows in all used columns.

Comment: @AnkitPandey So just change range you are inserting to include all the columns in the row.

Comment: @Ankit. I have updated the code to add a row for columns `A:C`. As per @Ron Rosenfeld's comment, it's as simple as changing the range

Answer (score 0):

Excel has alredy has remove duplicates option on the ribbon. Data->RemoveDuplicates. You can also do this with advanced filters.
If you need to do it with VBA, for example:

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$5").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

Where you need to put your range and your column.
A very useful tool to retrieve VBA code for determined action is the macro recorder, in the ribbon, Developer -> RecordMacro, perform you action and stop recording and then you can check the code generated for the actions you recorded. Its not the cleanest code but you can find there the lines of code for the specific actions you want.

Hope that helps